# How do i create new table in database from same entity JPA Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a new table every day with the full date as table name if the day is new create table for the that day

I have seen that when I change @Table(name="") name to a new string it make a new table but I can't automate this work

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders_25_10_2021")
public class game2data {
@Id
private int cid;
private String name;
private Integer address;
private Integer gender;
private String date;
private String Done;
```

In simple words, I want to pass the name of @Table(name="") as a variable with dynamic according to date.

Comment: I can't think of a solution that will make you able to do this and get the benefits of JPA abstractions. You can however take the bare metal path and write some runnable with an infinite loop that checks the time and creates a new table every day. or maybe do some sort of cronjob or something like that. Can you give more information about your business logic? because you might be able to rearchitect your database in a way in which you don't have to write such a hacky solution.

Comment: That's not possible. It looks like you are trying to create partitioning on the JPA level. Why don't you use the database features? What database are you using?

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: @Simon Martinelli  in simple words, i want to create a new table with the same columns mentioned above, every day automatically without changing the name String  in @Table() annotation

Comment: That's called partitioning in the database world. Please read the documentation. And should be done with the database and not with JPA (despite JPA cannot do that at all) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this custom naming strategy by extending SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy and overriding its toPhysicalTableName method :

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TableNamingStrategy extends SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy {
  private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd_MM_YYYY");
  public static final PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl INSTANCE =
      new PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl();

  @Override
  public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
    if (!name.getText().equals("game2data"))
      return name;
    StringBuilder customName =
        new StringBuilder("orders").append('_').append(DATE_FORMATTER.format(LocalDate.now()));
    return new Identifier(customName.toString(), name.isQuoted());
  }
}
```

**and** registering it in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.stackoverflow.questions.TableNamingStrategy
```

**and** removing the `@Table` annotation from the game2data entity.
**This method is limited by the fact [table names are determined at application start-up.](https://www.geekyhacker.com/2021/09/14/change-table-name-value-on-runtime-in-hibernate/)**

---

As a proof of concept, [here's a way](https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-69734630) to update the table name every day by extending `StatementInspector`. By using this, **you won't be able to read old data**. You'll also have to use custom implementations of the `JpaRepository`'s methods to create the new table every day before you insert data in it.

Comment: I have to add this code in same entity class or make a new class? please assist

Comment: You have to make a new class that extends SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy, and give the fully qualified class name to `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy`. In my example the class name was `TableNamingStrategy` and the package was `com.stackoverflow.questions` but you could give the class any name you prefer and adapt your `application.properties` file accordingly.

Comment: Hey I have a simple question can do schedule this function for every 24 hrs soo that this automatically make a new table without restarting the server

Comment: and one more thing i want to make one more function for another table with same **_Date formate I can I doo this also

Comment: hii I just want to ask that how can we call this naming strategy inside a controller or service file of our project. I am a beginner please help me.